# What is TensorFlow Variable naming?

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow the first thing I learned to create a variable is

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((2,2)), name="weights")
```

But I have a silly question as:

When I name the variable as "weights", shouldn't W be its name as well? What's the difference between "W" and "weights" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`W` is a Python variable that contains the reference to the `tensorflow Variable`. When you are dealing with creating model (in Python) you need to use `W`.

But, suppose you have a bug in your model. So, you query tensorflow for the model details. Tensorflow prints the output, but with default naming because it does not know what name did you gave to its object in Python, and increases the difficulty in debugging. So, passing `name` attribute explicitly assigns the specified name to the tensorflow object.